# findChessboardCorners is unable to find chessboard beyond 3x3

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to calibrate a camera in python with the chessboard method.
This is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

x = 3
y = 3
# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((y*x,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:x,0:y].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (x,y),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (x,y), corners2,ret)
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
img = cv2.imread('pic0.jpg')
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
# undistort
mapx,mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx,dist,None,newcameramtx,(w,h),5)
dst = cv2.remap(img,mapx,mapy,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# crop the image
x,y,w,h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('calibresult.png',dst)
```

x and y are used for the size of the pattern.
This is the image I am working with.
[image]

The findChessboardCorners method seems to be unable to find a chessboard pattern beyond the size of 3x3. I already tried to binarize the image and to increase the contrast but I am unable to retrieve a bigger pattern.
Is the image I am working with too bad or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it find it of size 3 becuase you are telling to find size 3... `cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (x,y),None)` that `(x,y)` is the shape of your chessboard

Comment: I use x and y to give the pattern size, 3x3 is the only way I found one so far, I tried it with 3x4, 4x3 and so on.

Comment: your chessboard is 14 by 6 (or 6 by 14). you count the inner corners  (where the black squares touch) [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners) is the doc page

Comment: Yeah you are right, I am dumb. I didn't try the 14x6 but just played with the pattern size, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nullman says, you are defining the size of the chessboard inner corners as 3x3. In the sample image you provided, the inner corner size is 14x6. Therefore, the code would be:

```
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (14,6),None)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `(x,y)` in

```
cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (x,y),None)
```

is the shape of your board, which you specified as 3 by 3
reading [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners) I can see that you are supposed to count inner corners (where the black squares touch) so your board is actually `(14,6)`